# CSS: How can I make pseudo elements width dynamically changing when the browser window size changes?

Tags: html, css

I've build me a progress bar to make a progress visible for my customers. When you checkout my code you can see that I've build it that way that I can set the `width` of the `li::after` elements from 0 - 100% which should define the progress of each step.

Now I've the problem that when I minimize the window that the `::after` element of the first `li` undermines the `next li` which is not good. It should minimize and only fill the width of the available space between each elements.

---

So for example when step one is `40 %` done the `::after` should change the width to `40 %`:

[image]

And when the width get's changed to `60 %`, the green `::after` element is a bit more to the next step. When you minimize the window now with `40 %` set to the first `::after` element, the width of it don't changes with the new window size and undermines the next element which should be avoided. This is my problem.

---

I've tried so much but I don't get it. So how can I solve this issue?

```css
.progress-container {
    position: relative;
}

.progress-container::before {
    background-color: #dadada;
    width: 80%;
    height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    top: 53px;
    content: '';
}

.progress-bar {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.progress-bar h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.progress-bar li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.progress-bar li::before {
    content: attr(data-step);
    display: block;
    background: #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 7em;
    height: 7em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    line-height: 7em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.progress-bar li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 11px;
    top: 53px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 2.9em;
    z-index: 2;
}

.progress-bar li.progress-1.is-active::before,
.progress-bar li.progress-1.is-active::after {
    background: green;
}

.progress-bar li.progress-1::after {
    width: 40%;
}

.progress-bar li.progress-2.is-active::before,
.progress-bar li.progress-2.is-active::after {
    background: yellow;
}

.progress-bar li.progress-3.is-active::before,
.progress-bar li.progress-3.is-active::after {
    background: orange;
}

.progress-bar li.progress-4.is-active::before {
    background: red;
}

.progress__last {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.progress__last:after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-container">
    <ol class="progress-bar">
        <li class="progress-1 is-active" data-step="1">
            <h3>1</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-2 is-active" data-step="2">
            <h3>2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-3 is-active" data-step="3">
            <h3>3</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-4 progress__last is-active" data-step="4">
            <h3>4</h3>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I usually create a div that is that line - positioned relative, and inside that div another one - positioned absolute. Width of that div inside should be set dynamically in JS and background color is that green you have, hope the idea helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the code like below and use some background trick. The idea is to use backgroud coloration on the main element to define the percentage.

I also used a CSS variable to make it easy.

```css
.progress-container {
    margin:5px;
}

.progress-bar {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #666666;    
    background:
      /*The gradient that will hide the main one based on the percentage*/
      linear-gradient(#dadada,#dadada) 100% 30px/ calc(100% - var(--p,100%)) 10px,
      /*the main gradient with 3 colors*/
      linear-gradient(to right,
        green  0             ,green  calc(100%/3),   
        yellow calc(100%/3)  ,yellow calc(2*100%/3), 
        orange calc(2*100%/3),orange calc(3*100%/3))
      0 30px/100% 10px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.progress-bar h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.progress-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.progress-bar li:first-child {
  margin-left:-5px;
}
.progress-bar li:last-child {
  padding-right:0;
  margin-right:-5px;
}

.progress-bar li::before {
    content: attr(data-step);
    display: block;
    background: #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4em;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.progress-bar li.progress-1.is-active::before {
  background:green;
}

.progress-bar li.progress-2.is-active::before {
  background: yellow;
}


.progress-bar li.progress-3.is-active::before {
  background: orange;
}


.progress-bar li.progress-4.is-active::before {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-container">
    <ol class="progress-bar" style="--p:20%">
        <li class="progress-1 is-active" data-step="1" >
            <h3>1</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-2" data-step="2">
             <h3>2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-3" data-step="3">
            <h3>3</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-4 progress__last" data-step="4">
            <h3>4</h3>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="progress-container">
    <ol class="progress-bar" style="--p:50%">
        <li class="progress-1 is-active" data-step="1">
            <h3>1</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-2 is-active" data-step="2" >
            <h3>2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-3" data-step="3">
           <h3>3</h3> 
        </li>
        <li class="progress-4 progress__last" data-step="4">
            <h3>4</h3>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="progress-container">
    <ol class="progress-bar"  style="--p:75%">
        <li class="progress-1 is-active" data-step="1">
            <h3>1</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-2 is-active" data-step="2" >
            <h3>2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-3 is-active" data-step="3">
            <h3>3</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-4 progress__last" data-step="4">
            <h3>4</h3>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="progress-container">
    <ol class="progress-bar"  style="--p:100%">
        <li class="progress-1 is-active" data-step="1">
            <h3>1</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-2 is-active" data-step="2" >
            <h3>2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-3 is-active" data-step="3" >
            <h3>3</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="progress-4 progress__last is-active" data-step="4">
            <h3>4</h3>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: But this way it's not longer possible to make the ::after for example 40% width to show the way to the next element u know what I mean? So when for example the half way to the 2 element is done, the ::after should be also have the half width. This is what it makes so complicated.

Comment: @Mr.Jo can be more precise? because we can adjust the background-size to have less  coloration

Comment: Updated my question!

Comment: @Mr.Jo I used a variable that will define the overal percentage, you simply need to use with the correct element and add is-active class to that element and the previous ones

Comment: My cat vomited and I needed to clean it so I'm back now. I've implemented your solution and it works great. But now my "responsive" design don't works anymore. I've build it with @media tabs before. So when a max-width of 800px is noticed the progress-bar changed to a vertically solution. Is this possible here too?

Comment: @Mr.Jo yes you can, here is an idea : https://jsfiddle.net/75jvpLr3/ ... you basically change the gradient and the alignment

Comment: You're an artist. Let me check if I can get all running and then I'll check your answer.

Comment: When I leave the h3 which titles every step, the background is not centered :|. My fault, but how can I change this?

Comment: @Mr.Jo you need to adjust the backgroud position, can you show me how it looks actually?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :) Merry Christmas and a happy new year to you!

Comment: I've just found out that this solution don't works in IE11. How can I fix this?

Comment: @mr IE doesn't support CSS variable, so simply remove them and use common CSS to define the values

Comment: Oh okay. So I can define it in <script> tags in PHP for example?

Comment: @Mr.Jo instead of the shrothand you can use background-size to define the size and you will have it in a separate property that you can easily set inline for example